# Scala scala.xml.XML.load(is: InputStream) is closing ZipInputStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, inputstream

I am extracting zip files in memory suing scala as shown below:

```
val rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/path")
          .flatMap { 
          case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) => {
             val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open())
             Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry()).takeWhile(_ != null)
               .flatMap { _ =>
                      val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
                      val root = scala.xml.XML.load(br);
                      val namespace = root.head.namespace
                      //other stuff
                    }
          }    
    }
```

Problem with this code is, it reads only 1st XML file inside the zip and then closes the ZipInputStream automatically and I get the error as:

```
 java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
```

I have few zip files and each zip contains XML files, my goal is to parse each of the XML file. As I am newbie to Scala I am not sure whether I am doing anything wrong or `scala.xml.XML.load` itself is closing the stream.

Comment: Isn't closing the buffered reader created in the innermost `flatMap` closing the stream?

Comment: @HristoIliev I didn't close the `BufferedReader`, I even tried without `BufferedReader` and by moving `BufferedReader` outside the `flatMap`, neither worked

Comment: I did a bit of digging. Scala XML uses the Java SAX parser. It takes input from `org.xml.sax.InputSource` objects (created [here](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/03f5cbc42270a5f514c0e210f703898258df695f/shared/src/main/scala/scala/xml/XML.scala#L24)) and according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) the stream gets closed as part of parser clean-up. I guess you have to read the content of each XML file in memory from the ZIP stream and create separate memory streams.